# How to do times and device in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to take two values that is in ms to devide them and *1000.

```
Select 
 COUNT_STAR AS exec_count,
 SUM_TIMER_WAIT AS total_latency,
 (SUM_TIMER_WAIT/COUNT_STAR)*1000 AS 'AVG_latency(sec)'
 FROM dbname
```

The following is working

```
(SUM_TIMER_WAIT/COUNT_STAR) AS 'AVG_latency(ms)'

    exec_count      total_latency    AVG_latency(ms)
    13              3282064379000    252466490692.3077
    13              23618632000      1816817846.1538
    1               10046560000      10046560000.0000
```

However when I add the *1000 to convert to seconds I get a bad value

```
(SUM_TIMER_WAIT/COUNT_STAR)*1000 AS 'AVG_latency(sec)'

exec_count     total_latency    AVG_latency(sec)
13             3282064379000    25246649069230.7692
13             23618632000      181681784615.3846
1              10046560000      1004656000000.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving a bad value rather it is just extending the values to more decimal points.

You can use [FLOOR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) to get it to the nearest inetger value. Try this:

```
Select 
 COUNT_STAR AS exec_count,
 SUM_TIMER_WAIT AS total_latency,
 FLOOR((SUM_TIMER_WAIT/COUNT_STAR)*1000) AS 'AVG_latency(sec)'
FROM dbname
```

The Floor will returns the largest integer value not greater than 'AVG_latency'.

Answer (score 0):

They're not "bad" values, you're just asking for "more":

```
original: 252466490692.3077
* 1000:   25246649069230.7692

original: 1816817846.1538
* 1000:   181681784615.3846

original: 10046560000.0000
* 1000:   1004656000000.0000
```

Notice how everything lines up, but the decimal place is shifted by 2 places - that means you're doing `* 100`, not `* 1000`.

Comment: Is these a way to get the value to look like this 2.52 (sec)

Comment: if they're in milliseconds, then you should be dividing by 1000. by multiplying, you're converting them to microseconds. Try `/ 1000` instead.

Comment: ((SUM_TIMER_WAIT/COUNT_STAR)/1000) AS 'AVG_latency(sec)',

252466490.69230769

Comment: add this to google and you get the correct result

((3282064379000/13)*1000)

2.5246649e+14